# Design route without Route::controller

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

`Route::controller` deprecated in Laravel 5.3,
Now I want to design my routes but I don't know how can I do this without `Route::controller` because I don't want define `Route::get` for each route and I want handle the parameters in my controller .

for example, these are my routes :

```
http://domain.com/images/10/pic.jpg (in this route I need 10 as $file_id and pic.jpg as $file_name)
http://domain.com/images/crop/200x100/10/pic.jpg (in this route I need crop as $action, 200x100 as $size, 10 as $file_id and pic.jpg as $file_name)
```

How I can do it without `Route::controller` ?

Comment: you can use `Route::resource()`

Comment: @RimonKhan thanks, but resource create crud methods, I don't need these methods and I want use my own methods

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to create new routes is to use a resource controller (`Route::resource()`) or defining your own routes via `Route::get`,`Route::post` and so on.

There is **no faster** and non-deprecated method at the moment. Anyway, the `Resource::controller()` function might be extracted to another package, as Taylor Otwell stated in his [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.2-deprecations).

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same dilemma as you, when the Route::controller was dropped with no obvious reason.

This is why I wrote a class called AdvancedRoute, which serves as a drop in replacement.

It can be used by simply replacing Route::controller with AdvancedRoute::controller like this:

AdvancedRoute::controller('customers','CustomerController');

Full information how to install and use find at the GitHub repo at:

https://github.com/lesichkovm/laravel-advanced-route